# How to validate the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to Windows Application Development.

I have a Grid view column of type 'Data Grid View Text Box Column' which allows the user to enter records. In that grid I have two columns that are Qty & Rate. These two columns should accept only numbers. How do I validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kyle solution is closer, however you want to capture the key press event for this purpose you have to handle two events

[Occurs when a control for editing a cell is showing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  // here you need to attach the on key press event to handle validation
  DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
  tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);

  e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);
}
```

/// your key press event

```
private void dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  // when user did not entered a number
  if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)
        && (Keys)e.KeyChar != Keys.Back)  // check if backspace is pressed
  {
    // set handled to cancel the event to be proceed by the system
    e.Handled = true;
    // optionally indicate user that characters other than numbers are not allowed
    // MessageBox.Show("Only numbers are allowed");
  }
}
```

Cheers @Riyaz

## Edit

You need to check if the `(Keys)e.KeyChar != Keys.Back` for more functional keyborad keys please refer msdn article for system windows forms keys [Keys enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir @Waqas Raja.

Sir its working perfectly just need a little help. I want to allow user to press backspace if one enters wrong number. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Please check my edited answer. You only need to check if the `(Keys)e.KeyChar != Keys.Back`, if it worked please don't forget to mark as answer... Thanks!

Comment: Sir I am trying to allow the user to input "." with the this condition `if(!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && (Keys)e.KeyChar != Keys.Back && (Keys)e.KeyChar != Keys.Decimal)`
but it isn't working.

Is there any alternate way? @Waqas Raja

Comment: as you can type the dot ( `.` ) why don't you simply do this `e.KeyChar != '.'`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Waqas Raja It Woks :-)

Comment: Sir Can You please help me for generating report using ReportViewerControl? @Waqas Raja

Comment: @WaqasRaja sir i try your anwser and i get one problem. My question link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527383/add-decimal-point-set-cursor-possition-on-keypress-event-gridview-cell-text.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can modify Waqas code buy doing something like this

```
 private void dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)  
         (sender)).EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString() ==  
         "1")//Enter your column index
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                  && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Enter only Numeric Values");

            }
            else
            {
              //  MessageBox.Show("Enter only Numeric Values");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works fine but I don't want user to enter the characters only.

This gives error after the text box's focus is lost. I want user to give error the moment user presses the character key. @Kyle

Comment: Is it possible to do so.? If it is then please help me sir. @Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this helps.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var value = (((DataGridView) (sender)).CurrentCell).Value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                var txt = value.ToString();
                double result;
                double.TryParse(txt, out result);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    (((DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell).Value = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input.");
                }
            }
        }
```